# Font Awesome - Using a different font family

Tags: html, css, fonts

I've downloaded an web-page template and trying to edit it. The template is using Font Awesome icons and I love those icons. But the thing is, template is using Font Awesome as the font family for texts and I need to use Turkish characters such as ç,ğ,ş,İ, which Font Awesome does not support. I want to use Font Awesome icons, but change the text fonts. I tried to add another font-face but it did not work. Is there any easy way to change the font for texts, to for example Calibri or something common like that?

Comment: can you post the css, should just be a small change.

Comment: check your `body` or `html` css, there may be something like this: `font-family:'font-awesome;` in there which would be stopping you from getting letters.